# Chai Testing type of component within another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tags, chai, enzyme

I am trying to test an HTML tag `<Tr></Tr>`. Here is my code:

```
const children = (<h1>Test</h1>);
    const renderComponent = () => shallow(
      <Table>
        <Tr>
          {children}
        </Tr>
      </Table>
    );


    describe("<Tr />", () => {
      it("should render a <Tr> tag within a <Table> tag", () => {
        const renderedComponent = renderComponent();
        expect(renderedComponent.type()).toEqual("tr");
      });
    });
```

Issue here is that my test targets the tag `<Table>` as the type of `renderedComponent` and thus returns a failed test.

How can I change my `expect` test to find the second tag `<Tr>` rather than the first `<Table>`?

To note:

I am using a new library named styled-component which enables me to transform HTML tags into the most basic React Components which contains css as Js.

```
import styled from "styled-components";

    const Table = styled.table`
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%
    `;

    export default Table;
```

Thus, my components are limited to their own Tag and do not contain anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have uppercase `Table` and `Tr`, [JSX compiler expects to have such component defined](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized). So just use lowercase for HTML tags.

This work for me:

```
const children = (<h1>Test</h1>);
const renderComponent = () => shallowWithIntl(
    <table>
        <tr>
            {children}
        </tr>
    </table>
);


describe('<Tr />', () => {
    it('should render a <Tr> tag ', () => {
        const renderedComponent = renderComponent();
        expect(renderedComponent.type()).to.equal('table');
    });

    it('should have children', () => {
        const renderedComponent = renderComponent();
        expect(renderedComponent.contains(children)).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I must have not been precise enough in my description. I am creating React components, that is why my HTML tags start with capital letters. Also, in my first test, I want to see if `renderedComponent.type()).to.equal('tr');` and not `renderedComponent.type()).to.equal('table');`

Comment: So paste contents of your `Table` and `Tr` components. Concerning: `table` vs `tr`: Not sure how I should understand this sentence: `However, now it tests the first tag to equal which obviously is wrong.` So I made a guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry, I am stil learning to code and therefore to be precise with my questions. I need to test my Tr tag, in my Chai test (the first it()), I want to target the second HTML tag in `renderedComponent` which is `Tr` and test it to see if it is present within <Table>. Also, I guess changing my test description to  `it('should render a <Tr> tag  in the <Table> tag'` would make it a lot clearer -_-

Comment: Could you update your question with these comments and with contents of `Table` and `Tr` components?

Comment: I updated the question in relation to comments, however I don't actually have any relevant content. I am just testing the component to be sure that it is not broken due to someone changing something in the basic configuration of the boilerplate.

Comment: If `Table` and `Tr` react components are not defined as components, it is right that they are undefined. If you don't know what am I writing about, you should really talk to senior member of your team.

Comment: Did what I could to explain why my Components are empty. Also, I have tested a number of Components and they are fine. The real issue here (apart from my beginnings as a coder) , does not concern the components as being defined as react components.